# How to generate ajax calls from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, coffeescript

I'm a bit new to JavaScript and I have a really silly question: How can I call a function I have in a Coffeescript file from HTML?

I want the users to be able to select the language they see my site, but don't want my html to be reloaded for that.

I am using i18next to make the translations and now what I need is to add some buttons to select the language.

The function will reload just a section of the page is in my coffee file.

So, how can I call this function from my html file?

PS: If you can show me some examples it'll be great!

Comment: Raad http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just a note: there's no need for `this style of text` for names of programming languages. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use these code with jquery :)

```
var data = {
    'value': $("#myb option:selected").val(),
    'link': 'kapil'
   }
$.post("your_file",data, function(response) {
        alert(response);               
        });
```

Comment: Ok, if my link is like: `{{ STATIC_URL }}js/game{% if not debug %}.min{% endif %}.js?b=20130927`, how can I call an specific function?

Comment: Can you let me know which programing language is using for that operation?

Comment: html5, coffeescript, craftyjs (those on the front-end)

Comment: Sorry dude i cant help you for these because do not have lot of knowledge of  html5, coffeescript, craftyjs. Sorry! :(

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML code contains have button like

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="change();" >Submit</button>
```

Write a script to send ajax request:

```
function change(){
 $.ajax({
      url:"add url here",
      type:"POST",
      data:{"dataval":add} //add is a variable that contains value,
      success:function(response){
       alert(response);
      },
      error:function(r,e,s){ }
 });
 }
```

You can create html(for response) in success function and replace contents of div by response